# Как правильно подключить jquery к WordPress через cdn?

Tags: wordpress

Что нужно прописать в function.php и надо ли что-то прописывать в header.php?

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_enqueue_script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method', 11 );
function my_scripts_method() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js');
    }
}
```